# Polymorphic (owned) reference wrapper for class hierarchies

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

Rationale: I often have the requirement to own object instances, while preserving polymorphic behavior (i.e. own the object and hold it by pointer, or reference).

This is usually expressed as a pointer (most of the times, `std::unique_ptr<T>`), but when the pointer is stored in a `std::` container, client syntax becomes tricky (with - for example - vector iterators being dereferenced to a pointer - instead of a reference).

To avoid this, I have implemented a polymorphic wrapper for a (base) class, that holds a pointer to the base class, and allows it's population using a specialization.

The wrapper allows implicit conversion to the held type (as a `Base` [const] reference) and implements fast, non-intrusive cloning, for the held type. This is based on copy construction of the `Specialized` type and `stdex::details::polymorphic_clone<Base,Specialized>` template specialization, to clone the correct `Specialized` type).

Please review the code, and let me know if there are any pitfalls or design/implementation problems with it (one known limitation is described at the end).

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

namespace stdex {
    inline namespace details {

        /// @brief Deep copy construct from (Specialized&)*src
        ///
        /// @retval nullptr if src is nullptr
        /// @retval Specialized clone of *src
        ///
        /// @note Undefined behavior if src does not point to a Specialized*
        template<typename Base, typename Specialized>
        Base* polymorphic_clone (const Base* src) {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Specialized>::value,
                "Specialized is not a specialization of Base");

            if (src == nullptr)
                return nullptr;
            return new Specialized{ static_cast<const Specialized&>(*src) };
        }
    }

    /// @brief polymorphic reference interface over a base class
    ///
    /// Respects polymorphic behavior of class ref.
    /// Instances have deep copy semantics (clone) and
    /// "[const] Base&" interface
    ///
    /// @note Not regular: no trivial way to implement non-intrusive equality
    ///
    /// @note safe to use with standard containers
    template<typename Base>
    class polymorphic final
    {
    public:

        /// Functor capable to convert a Base* to it's specialized type
        /// and clone it (intrusive implementation can be used)
        ///
        /// example intrusive implementation (if supported by Base):
        /// []( const Base* src ) { return src->clone(); }
        typedef std::function<Base* (const Base*)>  clone_functor;

        /// @brief construct (takes ownership of ptr)
        template<typename Specialized, typename CloneSpecialized>
        polymorphic(Specialized* ptr, CloneSpecialized functor) noexcept
        : instance_{ptr}, clone_{std::move(functor)}
        {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Specialized>::value,
            "Specialized is not a specialization of Base");
            static_assert(
            std::is_constructible<clone_functor, CloneSpecialized>::value,
            "CloneSpecialized is not valid for a clone functor");
        }

        // not implemented: UB cloning in case client provides specialized ptr
        // polymorphic(Base* ptr);

        // @note empty constructor for std:: containers support
        polymorphic() = default;

        polymorphic(polymorphic&&) = default;

        polymorphic(const polymorphic& other)
        // : polymorphic{std::move(other.clone())}
        : polymorphic{ other.clone() } // comment by @dyp
        {
        }

        // polymorphic& operator=(polymorphic other)
        polymorphic& operator=(polymorphic other) noexcept // comment by @dyp
        {
            std::swap(instance_, other.instance_);
            std::swap(clone_, other.clone_);
            return *this;
        }

        ~polymorphic() = default;

        /// @brief Cast to contained type
        /// @pre instance not moved
        /// @pre *this initialized with valid instance
        operator Base&() const
        {
            assert(instance_.get());
            return *instance_.get();
        }

        /// @brief Cast to contained type
        /// @pre instance not moved
        /// @pre *this initialized with valid instance
        operator const Base&() const
        {
            assert(instance_.get());
            return *instance_.get();
        }

    private:
        polymorphic clone() const
        {
            return { clone_(instance_.get()), clone_functor{clone_} };
        }

        std::unique_ptr<Base>   instance_;
        clone_functor           clone_;
    };

    // edited after comment by @dyp
    template<typename Base, typename Specialized, typename CF>
    polymorphic<Base> to_polymorphic(Specialized&& temp, CF functor)
    {
        return {
            new Specialized{std::move(temp)},
            typename polymorphic<Base>::clone_functor{std::move(functor)}
        };
    }

    template<typename Base, typename Specialized>
    polymorphic<Base> to_polymorphic(Specialized&& temp)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Specialized>::value,
        "Specialized is not a specialization of Base");

        return to_polymorphic<Base,Specialized>(
            std::move(temp), polymorphic_clone<Base,Specialized>
        );
    }

    template<typename Base, typename Specialized, typename ...Args>
    // polymorphic<Base> to_polymorphic(Args ...args)
    polymorphic<Base> to_polymorphic(Args&& ...args) // comment by @dyp
    {
        static_assert(std::is_constructible<Specialized, Args...>::value,
        "Cannot instantiate Specialized from arguments");

        return to_polymorphic<Base,Specialized>(
            std::move(Specialized{std::forward<Args...>(args...)}));
    }

    template<typename Base> using polymorphic_vector =
    std::vector<polymorphic<Base>>;

    template<typename Base, typename ...Args>
    polymorphic_vector<Base> to_polymorphic_vector(Args&& ...args)
    {
        // comment by @dyp (add std::forward)
        return {
            to_polymorphic<Base>(std::forward<Args>(args))...
        };
    }

} // stdex
```

Example use (using a class hierarchy based on `view`, a generic responder for HTTP requests - the implementation of view is not important here, I just had it in existing code):

```
stdex::polymorphic_vector<view> views = // explicit type for clarity
    stdex::to_polymorphic_vector<view>(
        echo_view{"/echo"}, // class echo_view : public view
        directory_view{"/static_files", "~/http-server/static"}
            // class directory_view : public view
    );

for(auto& v: views)
    if(v.matches(reuqest.url())) // bool view::matches(...);
        auto response = v.handle(request); // virtual view::handle(...) = 0;
```

Limitations of this implementation:

If you use multiple inheritance DO NOT USE `stdex::details::polymorphic_clone`. Write an implementation based on `dynamic_cast` instead, and use `to_polymorphic(Specialized&& temp, CF functor)`.

Comment: I didn't read the code yet, but could you explain how it is different from `std::reference_wrapper`? :)

Comment: @Morwenn, This class is different from `std::reference_wrapper` in two aspects: it owns the referenced instance (destroying it on scope exit) and it adds deep copy semantics for the held reference (non-intrusive cloning for an arbitrary type T).

Comment: `polymorphic{std::move(other.clone())}` the `move` seems unnecessary here, and prevents move elision.

Comment: `polymorphic& operator=(polymorphic other)` can probably be `noexcept`

Comment: `polymorphic<Base> to_polymorphic(Specialized&& temp)` sounds like a job for default arguments.

Comment: `auto    clone_instance = clone_functor{std::move(functor)};` Why is this a named variable? And why don't you *move* from it when passing it to the ctor?

Comment: `polymorphic<Base> to_polymorphic(Args ...args)` Bug: missing `&&`. Similarly, in `to_polymorphic<Base>(args)`, missing `forward`.

Comment: `std::move(Specialized{...})` Another unnecessary and "harmful" move.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem with multiple inheritance here. OTOH, putting an object via reference into `polymorphic` via `to_derived` requires the user to make sure it's of the most-derived type, otherwise the cloning will slice.

Comment: Have you considered [Sean Parent's design](http://youtu.be/vxv74Mjt9_0?t=21m42s) of a container with polymorphic objects / local polymorphism?

Comment: @dyp - I have edited the code according to your comments; regarding Sean Parent's desing, I will watch it, but from what I've seen so far, he has a problem I've explicitly tried to avoid ( double de-reference from iterators: `vector<Base> a; (*a.begin())->virtual_fun();` ).

Comment: @utnapistim IIRC he hides the vector as an implementation detail of `document`.

Comment: @dyp - Ok, I haven't watched that far, but I considered wrapping the vector, and discarded it. The `to_polymorphic_vector` was just a function I added because I used polymorphic with vectors in client code. I chose to wrap the base pointer (instead of the vector) because I wanted a small utility wrapper that could be used just as easy, with other containers (but maybe Sean's presentation covers for that as well - I still haven't watched it :) ). It can be used easily without a container as well.

Comment: Note there's a quite implicit dependency between the clone function and the `unique_ptr`: The latter requires the former to use `new`. This is typically avoided by using an allocator, which does both, creation and deletion of elements.

Comment: `polymorphic{ std::other.clone() }` <- the `std::` should be left out. `std::forward(args)` should be `std::forward<Args>(args)`

Comment: @dyp You should really post a full answer when you have that many things to say. It would help everyone (and, IIRC, it is not the first time that you post enough comments in such a short time that could make a good answer) :)

Comment: @Morwenn I sometime use the comment section as a note pad (umm déjà-vu?) for minor things. When there's enough, I later collect the stuff and take some time to look at the design to make an answer. Didn't have that time yet.

Comment: Please try not to make so many edits at once.  You could make them in batches, or have someone post a full answer.

Comment: @Jamal, I will stop making edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you are not using [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) in the right way (i.e. use always `std::forward` when passing them around and not `std::move`). Fix it in the implementation of `to_polymorphic`, for example.

The assignment operator takes the `other` variable by value. Consider splitting it in a (default) move assignment operator `noexcept` that takes by rvalue-reference and a copy assignment operator that takes by const reference and performs a clone.

I don't see big problems in your implementation, but I recommend you to compare your approach with the Sean Parent's one (see also http://youtu.be/bIhUE5uUFOA), as already suggested by @dyp. One limitation, for example is that you are not using [Small Buffer Optimization](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/common-optimizations/#sbo) and you are forcing polymorphism trough inheritance.

There are other implementations providing value semantics along with polymorphism. For example, [Adobe poly](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__poly__related.html) and [Boost Type Erasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) (see usage examples [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/type-erasure-part-ii/)).

Comment: Link to Small Buffer Optimization example http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/common-optimizations/#sbo